# Автоматическое появление кнопки при подключении флешки/дискового раздела

Tags: c#, winforms

Делаю файловый менеджер. Нужно чтобы когда программу запускали отображались button'ы с выбором существующего дискового раздела или к примеру, если флешку подключить, то этот раздел сразу появится в виде кнопки. В данный момент все происходит по коду ниже. Просто есть четыре button'а с дисками "C", "D", "E", "F", но вдруг у пользователя есть только "C", тогда должна быть только кнопка "C".

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(@"C:\");
    }
```

Comment: [DriveInfo.GetDrives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives(v=vs.110).aspx) Для получения списка доступных

Comment: [пример с событиями подключения по USB](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16245706/2881286)

Comment: Извините, но если Вы разбираетесь, можете написать код? Мне не нужно так масштабно как в примере. Хотя бы просто чтобы отображались существующие дисковые разделы. Еще раз извините за наглость, но я пока не имею такого опыта... А идея мне очень нравится.

Comment: Просто скопируйте код метода `WndProc` по ссылке, указанной Grundy (и примените `DriveInfo`). Как вариант, можно использовать [WMI](http://stackoverflow.com/q/620144/5045688).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows на ура рассылает всем окнам верхнего уровня сообщения об изменении состоянии устройств. Успевайте только ловить (ну и отфильтровывать лишнее). Вас интересует сообщение *[WM_DEVICECHANGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363480(v=vs.85).aspx)* с событиями *DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL* и *DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE*, возникающее для типа устройств DBT_DEVTYPE_VOLUME.

Добавьте следующий код в любое окно верхнего уровня (не имеющее родителя):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;

namespace DeviceTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        /*WINAPI constants*/
        const int WM_DEVICECHANGE = 0x219;
        const int DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = 0x8000;
        const int DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE = 0x8004;
        const int DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME = 0x00000002;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PrintDrives();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Вывести список дисков в textbox
        /// </summary>
        public void PrintDrives()
        {
            DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(255);

            foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
            {
                sb.Append(d.Name);//это буква диска
                sb.Append(" ("+ d.DriveType.ToString()+")");
                if (d.IsReady == true)
                {
                    sb.Append(" - "+ d.VolumeLabel);//метка диска
                    sb.Append(", "+ d.DriveFormat);//файловая система
                }
                else sb.Append(" [not ready]");
                sb.AppendLine();
            }
            tbDrives.Text = sb.ToString();

        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            DEV_BROADCAST_HDR pHdr;
            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case WM_DEVICECHANGE: 
                    switch ((int)m.WParam)
                    {
                        case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL://устройство подключено

                            pHdr = (DEV_BROADCAST_HDR)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(DEV_BROADCAST_HDR));
                            if (pHdr.dbch_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME)
                            {
                                tbLog.Text+=Environment.NewLine+DateTime.Now.ToString()+" :"+"Volume was inserted";
                                PrintDrives();
                            }

                        break;

                        case DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE://устройство отключено

                        pHdr = (DEV_BROADCAST_HDR)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(DEV_BROADCAST_HDR));
                        if (pHdr.dbch_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME)
                        {
                            tbLog.Text += Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " :" + "Volume was removed";
                            PrintDrives();
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                    break;
            }

            base.WndProc(ref m);            
        }   

    }

    public struct DEV_BROADCAST_HDR
    {
        public int dbch_size;
        public int dbch_devicetype;
        public int dbch_reserved;
    }


}
```

Только учтите, что в код обработки данных сообщений нельзя вписывать длительные операции, так как система ждет их обработки всеми окнами и соответственно это может привести к подвисанию системы.

Comment: Спасибо, работает! Однако, это не совсем то, что нужно было. Галочку ставлю.