# Отобразить подключенное звуковое устройство

Tags: c#, winforms, bass.dll, bass.net

Как отобразить куда в данный момент поступает звук в компьютере? В динамики или в наушники. Нужно чтобы отображалось в Label или TextBox.

Comment: С использованием bass смотрите [SetNotify](http://bass.radio42.com/help/html/2615e67e-dfc1-8cef-7fb7-23fd4c8349ce.htm) (и далее по ссылкам). Или без bass смотрите [варианты](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33872895/5045688).

Answer (score 1):

**Введение**

Раз уж [подняли тему звуковых устройств и отображения их имени](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/696725/240512), имеет смысл написать ответ и здесь. Если динамики и наушники представлены в системе отдельными конечными устройствами (Endpoint), задача решается довольно просто с помощью любого аудио-API. С помощью того-же BASS.NET это делается примерно так:

```
BASS_DEVICEINFO[] devices=Bass.BASS_GetDeviceInfos();

foreach(BASS_DEVICEINFO dev in devices)
{
    if(dev.IsDefault)textBox1.Text=("Текущее устройство вывода звука: "+dev.name+" - "+dev.type.ToString());
}
```

Если нужно реагировать на изменения в устройствах в реальном времени, можно воспользоваться техникой, описанной [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/652517/240512), только вместо DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL обрабатывать DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED (0x0007).

Однако, это не всегда работает. Проблема в том, что в современных аудио-адаптерах обычно все аналоговые выходы представлены для системы одним конечным устройством, и переключение между динамиками и наушниками осуществляется либо автоматически драйвером, либо через утилиту производителя. В этом случае код выше бесполезен, так как он всегда будет выдавать одно и то же. Надежного решения тут нет, так как не все разъемы обладают системой детектирования кабеля, но можно попробовать использовать для определения активных разъемов Multimedia API и Device Topology API.

**Используемые API**

Для решения задачи нам понадобится [Windows Multimedia Device API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316556(v=vs.85).aspx) - для получения текущего конечного устройства вывода, и [Device Topology API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370825(v=vs.85).aspx) - для получения информации о разъемах. Необходимые классы определены в файлах `Objbase.h`, `Shobjidl.h`, `MMDeviceAPI.h` и `Devicetopology.h`. Поскольку это все COM-объекты, нам понадобятся декларации для использования их в управляемом коде. Их можно взять [в данной статье](https://smallsoft2.blogspot.ru/2017/09/windows.html), или получить Interop Assemblies самостоятельно с помощью средств Windows SDK. Для этого используются примерно такие команды:

> midl /out c:\tmp /header "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs...\Include\mmdeviceapi.h" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs...\Include\mmdeviceapi.idl"
>
> tlbimp /out:MMDevAPI.Interop.dll mmdeviceapi.tlb

Первая получает файл IDL, а вторая - сборку для подключения непосредственно к коду .NET.

**Пример программы**

Для вывода текущего устройства и его разъемов можно использовать такой код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace com_test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //вывод информации об устройстве
        string PrintDevice(IMMDevice dev)
        {
            IPropertyStore propertyStore = null;
            IDeviceTopology pDeviceTopology = null;
            IConnector pConnFrom = null;
            IConnector pConnTo = null;
            IPart pPart = null;
            IKsJackDescription pJackDesc = null;
            KSJACK_DESCRIPTION desc = new KSJACK_DESCRIPTION();

            StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder(300);            
            object o = null;

            int state = 0;
            uint con_count = 0;            

            try
            {
                //имя устройства
                dev.OpenPropertyStore(0/*STGM_READ*/, out o);                
                propertyStore = o as IPropertyStore;

                PropVariant friendlyName = new PropVariant();
                propertyStore.GetValue(Native.PKEY_Device_FriendlyName, out friendlyName);                
                res.AppendLine(friendlyName.Value.ToString());


                //form factor 
                PropVariant FormFactor = new PropVariant();
                propertyStore.GetValue(Native.PKEY_AudioEndpoint_FormFactor, out FormFactor);                
                EndpointFormFactor f=EndpointFormFactor.UnknownFormFactor;
                Enum.TryParse<EndpointFormFactor>(FormFactor.Value.ToString(), out f);
                res.AppendLine("Form factor: " + f.ToString());                

                //состояние устройства
                dev.GetState(ref state);                

                string str="";
                switch (state)
                {                    
                    case Native.DEVICE_STATE_DISABLE: str = ("Отключено"); break;
                    case Native.DEVICE_STATE_NOTPRESENT: str = ("Отсутствует"); break;
                    case Native.DEVICE_STATE_UNPLUGGED: str = ("Отключено"); break;
                }
                if(str!="")res.AppendLine(str);


                /* DEVICE TOPOLOGY */
                Guid iidDeviceTopology = new Guid("2A07407E-6497-4A18-9787-32F79BD0D98F");
                dev.Activate(ref iidDeviceTopology, (uint)CLSCTX.CLSCTX_ALL, IntPtr.Zero, out o);                
                pDeviceTopology = o as IDeviceTopology;

                pDeviceTopology.GetConnector(0, out pConnFrom);                

                try
                {
                    o = null;
                    pConnFrom.GetConnectedTo(out o);
                    pConnTo = o as IConnector;                    

                    pPart = (IPart)pConnTo;//QueryInterface

                    Guid iidKsJackDescription = new Guid("4509F757-2D46-4637-8E62-CE7DB944F57B");
                    pPart.Activate((uint)CLSCTX.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, ref iidKsJackDescription, out o);                    
                    pJackDesc = (IKsJackDescription)o;

                    if (pJackDesc != null)
                    {
                        con_count = 0;
                        pJackDesc.GetJackCount(out con_count);
                        if (con_count > 0)
                        {
                            StringBuilder sb ;

                            //отобразить информацию о разъемах
                            for (uint i = 0; i < con_count; i++)
                            {
                                pJackDesc.GetJackDescription(i, ref desc);

                                if (desc.IsConnected == 0) continue;
                                sb= new StringBuilder(100);
                                EPcxConnectionType con_type = (EPcxConnectionType)desc.ConnectionType;
                                EPcxGeoLocation loc = (EPcxGeoLocation)desc.GeoLocation;
                                res.Append("* ");

                                switch (con_type)
                                {
                                    case EPcxConnectionType.eConnType3Point5mm: sb.Append("Разъем 3.5 мм ");
                                        break;
                                    case EPcxConnectionType.eConnTypeAtapiInternal: sb.Append("Разъем ATAPI ");
                                        break;
                                    case EPcxConnectionType.eConnTypeRCA: sb.Append("Разъем RCA ");
                                        break;
                                    case EPcxConnectionType.eConnTypeQuarter: sb.Append("Разъем 1/2 дюйма ");
                                        break;
                                    case EPcxConnectionType.eConnTypeOtherAnalog: sb.Append("Аналоговый разъем ");
                                        break;
                                    case EPcxConnectionType.eConnTypeOtherDigital: sb.Append("Цифровой разъем ");
                                        break;
                                    default: sb.Append(con_type.ToString()+" ");
                                        break;
                                }

                                switch (loc)
                                {
                                    case EPcxGeoLocation.eGeoLocFront: sb.Append("- Передняя панель");
                                        break;
                                    case EPcxGeoLocation.eGeoLocRear: sb.Append("- Задняя панель");
                                        break;
                                    case EPcxGeoLocation.eGeoLocHDMI: sb.Append("- HDMI");
                                        break;
                                    case EPcxGeoLocation.eGeoLocNotApplicable: sb.Append("- Расположение не определено");
                                        break;
                                    default: sb.Append("- "+loc.ToString());
                                        break;
                                }


                                res.AppendLine(sb.ToString());


                            }//end for
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            res.AppendLine("* Нет разъемов");                            
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        res.AppendLine("* Не удалось получить информацию о разъемах");                        
                    }
                    ;


                }
                catch (COMException ex)
                {
                    if ((uint)ex.HResult == 0x80070490 /*E_NOTFOUND*/)
                    {
                        res.AppendLine("Не подключен");                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        res.AppendLine("COM error: " + ex.Message);                        
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    res.AppendLine("Не удалось получить информацию о разъемах: " + ex.Message);                    
                }                

            }
            finally
            {
                //clean up resources                
                if (dev != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(dev);
                if (propertyStore != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(propertyStore);

                if (pDeviceTopology != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pDeviceTopology); pDeviceTopology = null; }
                if (pConnFrom != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pConnFrom); pConnFrom = null; }
                if (pConnTo != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pConnTo); pConnTo = null; }
                if (pPart != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pPart); pPart = null; }
                if (pJackDesc != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pJackDesc); pJackDesc = null; }                
            }

            return res.ToString();
        }


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();  
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MMDeviceEnumerator devenum = new MMDeviceEnumerator();//Create CoClass
            IMMDeviceEnumerator deviceEnumerator = (IMMDeviceEnumerator)devenum;

            IMMDevice defDevice = null;
            IPropertyStore propertyStore = null;

            try
            {
                object o = null;

                // * default device *                
                deviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eConsole, out o);
                defDevice = o as IMMDevice;

                textBox1.Text = "Текущее устройство вывода звука: " + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
                textBox1.Text += PrintDevice(defDevice);
                textBox1.Select(0, 0);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                //clean up resources
                if (devenum != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(devenum);
                if (deviceEnumerator != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(deviceEnumerator);                
                if (defDevice != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(defDevice);
                if (propertyStore != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(propertyStore);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Здесь интерфейс `IMMDeviceEnumerator` используется для определения текущего устройства вывода. Затем делается попытка для него получить `IKsJackDescription` и вывести для всех активных разъемов тип и место размещения. Понятно, невозможно достоверно отличить динамики от наушников (потому что разъемы у них совершенно одинаковые), но какие-то выводы из этого можно извлечь.